# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string using grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to solve this error as I Just use the GridView to do my update, but prompt out this error.

In the Add.apsx.cs the date I set toString("yyyy-MM-dd") to store in database.

But Still come out this error when I want to update.

I have to put what inside my gridview to solve this problem?

```css
smdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_BOD", Staff_BOD.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="Staff_Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Id" HeaderText="Staff_Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Staff_Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Name" HeaderText="Staff_Name" SortExpression="Staff_Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_UserName" HeaderText="Staff_UserName" SortExpression="Staff_UserName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Password" HeaderText="Staff_Password" SortExpression="Staff_Password" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Gender" HeaderText="Staff_Gender" SortExpression="Staff_Gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_BOD" HeaderText="Staff_BOD" SortExpression="Staff_BOD"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Email" HeaderText="Staff_Email" SortExpression="Staff_Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Address" HeaderText="Staff_Address" SortExpression="Staff_Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Salary" HeaderText="Staff_Salary" SortExpression="Staff_Salary" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_Position" HeaderText="Staff_Position" SortExpression="Staff_Position" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_CNo" HeaderText="Staff_CNo" SortExpression="Staff_CNo" />
            </Columns>
```

Comment: I was searching for a date field. Did you mean **DOB**, a common abbreviation of Date Of Birth, instead of **BOD** (birth of date??)

Answer (score 1):

If your database column is a `DateTime` column, you don't need to format the date or cast it to a string before sending it as a parameter to the database.

Just use:

```
smdSelect.Parameters.Add("@Staff_BOD", Staff_BOD.SelectedDate);
```

Comment: It depends on how the date is defined in the database, but that _should_ indeed be a date, datetime or timestamp field (depending on the database), and not a string.